# RethinkDB: How do I create a custom duplicate check on insert

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I want to bulk insert an array of data using NodeJS and RethinkDB but I don't want to insert existing records (where name & value already has a record, I don't want to dupcheck on primary key id).

```
[
  {name:"Robert", value:"1337"},
  {name:"Martin", value:"0"},
  {name:"Oskar", value:"1"}
]
```

If any of the above values already exist, don't insert, but update "value".

My current working solution is that I loop through the array and first check if it exists using a filter, if not, i insert it. But it's very slow on 10.000 records.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have that kind of concept in RethinkDB. I tried to read the doc more. To insert a new document, use `insert`, to update field, use `update`, to replace to a whole new document, use `replace`(the primary key won't change)...So I don't think it's possible in RethinkDB.

Here is some way you can make it run faster:

- Create a compound index contains those two fields: `name` and `value`
  Then using that index to check for existence instead of using `filter`
- Generate your own `id` field, instead of letting RethinkDB generated it. Therefore, you know the primary key, and use it to look up document with `get` which will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement in a RethinkDB project, but in that case the primary key was being checked for duplicates, and it was also custom instead of being auto-generated.

What you could do is run an [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) or [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) two-step check. First pick a single object from your array, then filter the database for the name-value pairs of your current object. If the results come up null, it is unique. If not, you have a pre-existing record with same details.

Depending on the result, you can then pass on the control to next step which will either insert the new document or update existing one. It will be simpler if you use a flag for this in `async.waterfall`.